# Adding `off-topic` quick choices to the menu

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, off-topic

In my experience, most of the off-topic questions we have belong to Super User or Signal processing (eventualy, but it's rare, to Stack Overflow). The menu that comes out when flagging a question as off-topic, shows just the `Meta` choice, and a general off-topic one. It's up to the voter to specify the right place in the comments.

Would it be useful to put also these entries?

Comment: I downvote because I disagree with the request being acted upon, but I do consider this a very useful one. It was a good thing to think of, the statistics I have access to, that you do not, I looked at only a week ago thinking about this. There was no way you would know this and questions are regularly given comments of, "Try Superuser"

Comment: @Kortuk: no problem, I just wanted to throw the stone in the pond :) I remember of seeing some questions which are flagged off topic, but probably it's true that it's not worth the effort

Answer (score 2):

No, there are almost no migrations on our site. Here are our stats on migrations over the last 90 days:

- Super User : 5 migrations (1 rejected)
- DSP : 3 migrations
- English : 1 migration
- meta.EE : 1 migration
- DIY : 1 migration

I am sorry to say the number of flagged requests is greater than this but these are the only posts that make the cut and I do not have statistics on how many were rejected. Right now I do not consider an automated migration path useful. 11 migrations from our site in 90 days, moderators can handle that and we take the time to ask the target site if the question fits.

Comment: I don't mean a direct migration path, just a shortcut to indicate the vote quickly. Aren't the things separate?

Comment: @clabacchio, if there is a shortcut and 5 people vote that it migrates it to their site. I do not know of something else, if there is something else it does not bother me to have that feature. On SO and such where you have the choices it is automatically handling migration.

Comment: @clabacchio, As a side note here, when we close things for off topic, ie. If we are flagged for it, we will look at it and see if there is a migration path.